# Javascript: SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, sequelize.js, es6-promise

I am on Node 8 with [Sequelize.js](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/)

Gtting the following error when trying to use `await`.

`SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

Code:

```
async function addEvent(req, callback) {
    var db = req.app.get('db');
    var event = req.body.event

    db.App.findOne({
        where: {
            owner_id: req.user_id,
        }
    }).then((app) => {

                let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    setTimeout(() => resolve("done!"), 6000)

                })

               // I get an error at this point 
               let result = await promise;

               // let result = await promise;
               //              ^^^^^
               // SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
            }
    })
}
```

Getting the following error:

```
               let result = await promise;
                            ^^^^^
               SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `then((app) => {` this anonymous function is not marked as `async`

Comment: Probably better to just return the promise in the `then` callback and move it down the chain rather than awaiting it...

Comment: I find it kinda wierd the way your trying to get the promise resolve, why your not using .then() ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`addEvent` is a mixture of `async..await` and raw promises. `await` is syntactic sugar for `then`. It's either one or another. A mixture results in incorrect control flow; `db.App.findOne(...).then(...)` promise is not chained or returned and thus is not available from outside `addEvent`.

It should be:

```
async function addEvent(req, callback) {
    var db = req.app.get('db');
    var event = req.body.event

    const app = await db.App.findOne({
        where: {
            owner_id: req.user_id,
        }
    });

    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve("done!"), 6000)
    })

    let result = await promise;
}
```

Generally plain callbacks shouldn't be mixed with promises. `callback` parameter indicates that API that uses `addEvent` may need to be promisified as well.

Answer (score 18):

You can run await statement only under async function.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

So, you can write your

```
}).then((app) => {
```

as

```
}).then(async (app) => {
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  You were the first, but b/c of clarity and depth in @estus answer, I marked it as correct!

Comment: Yaaaaay you made my day :D :D :D

Answer (score 3):

`async/await` only works if the immediate function has the async keyword, you need this:

```
...
    }).then(async app => {   // <<<< here

                let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    setTimeout(() => resolve("done!"), 6000)

                })

               // I get an error at this point 
               let result = await promise;

               // let result = await promise;
               //              ^^^^^
               // SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
            }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use await only inside a function which is async. Also you can await only a piece of code that returns a promise.

Here you are using await inside a different context. Better you use then() here to solve the problem.

await only works if the immediate function that encloses it is async.

Comment: How does this answer the question? You basically just restated what the error message says.