# Node Async Method Understanding

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have a method that I want to finish before any code after it can be ran but am lost in understand external links when is comes to this.

In one method I have the following code

```
var x = someMethod("1","2","3"); // Finish before anything below can be ran
```

The method itself is simple

```
function someMethod(x,y,z){
    if(1){
        return "sdfh"
    } else if(2){
        return "asdf"
    } else {
        return "ljkk"
    }
}
```

How can I retrieve x before continue the code below it. Ive seen examples of nested functions, await, async but am lost

Comment: In your case `someMethod` is synchronous so your code is correct. But if `someMethod` was asynchronous hits signature would be `async function someMethod(x,y,z)` and the call to it be `var x = await someMethod("1","2","3");`

Comment: Like this: https://repl.it/repls/LonelyAcidicWorkplaces

Comment: @Thom SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: @user3277468 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52975133/javascript-syntaxerror-await-is-only-valid-in-async-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
const someMethod = (x, y, z) => {
  ...
};

const otherMethod = async () => {
  let x = 'before value';
  console.log(`before someMethod x: ${x}`);
  // Finish before anything below can be ran
  x = await someMethod("1", "2", "3"); 
  console.log(`after someMethod x: ${x}`);
};
```

Basically you are defining the function which has the await call as an asynchronous function using the async keyword in the function declaration - and can signify the portion of the code which you would like to wait by prepending with await.  There are nuances to this - but hopefully this helps.

Comment: do i just call otherMethod() ? in code for x to be defined first then?

Answer (score 0):

Java script is single thread and synchronous. I recommend checking out JavaScript promises. However I would assume your code executes synchronously until it hits something like a AJAX that is asynchronous.
check this answer out:
[When is JavaScript synchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035645/when-is-javascript-synchronous#targetText=JavaScript%20is%20always%20synchronous%20and,%2C%20for%20example%2C%20Ajax%20calls).